# Google occasionally can't be reached through any browser

Tags: wireless-networking, google-chrome, firefox

Some times (like 5 or 6 times a day) I can't access `google.com` from any browser, or `google.com` related pages. Curiously, `google.com.br` is accessed normally.

This usually lasts from 30 seconds to 5 minutes, and then it comes back to normal. In firefox the error is

> The owner of www.google.com has configured their website improperly. To protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has not connected to this website.

And then it says that `The certificate is only valid for courier.push.apple.com`, which seems pretty odd to me. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

For chrome here is the error:

[image]

I'm accessing this through wireless. I haven't tested this from a cable connection yet. I'm thinking that it can be either security problems, or maybe an improperly configured router, but I can't figure out what is wrong.

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1**

- I'm running Linux in my computer and this never happens with this same computer on my other network or at work.
- Other computers in this network also present this behavior.

Comment: When it's happening can you ping google.com by name? How about by IP?  Have you tried changing to a different (public) DNS server yet?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I tried setting DNS 1 and 2 to `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` but the problem persisted. Pinging `8.8.8.8` is normal but doing it by name returns `64 bytes from gru09s19-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.29.110): icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=367 ms` over and over, which I thought was weird. But I haven't tried the ping stuff while google was unaccessible. Next time it happens I'll do it.

Comment: Hmm. `courier.push.apple.com` doesn't exist ...

Comment: `172.217.29.110` belongs to google.

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes, I have no idea what that apple address is doing there. It comes up with some safari issues where it's using `address.com` instead of `www.address.com`  apparently, but nothing comes up related to firefox or bad access to google.

Answer (score -2):

This to me sounds like more of a virus (`malware`), I'd run your anti-virus protection and `Malwarebytes Anti-malware`.

If it finds nothing, there are two other things I can think of...

1. Make sure your computer's clock is set to your timezone and that's it's got the right time.
2. Reset your `Internet`.

Comment: This almost-surely isn't a virus. I'm running Linux in my computer and this never happens on my other network and at work. Other computers in this network also present this behavior. I'll edit the question with this information. Also, what do you mean by "reset your internet"? You mean reset the router?

Comment: Just to be clear. I'm pretty sure it isn't a virus **in my OS**, but it might as well be something in the router.

Comment: Yes reset your router is what I mean.